# Can not run run command on Postgres container from bash script

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run a sql script upon a postgreSQL container in k8S
If i run my commands in the command line one by one , it works.
However if i run the script file it does not trying to connect to port `8080`.
There is nothing running on port `8080` and my postgres pod uses the default port of 5432
I can connect to my pod if i run the commands one by one, i can connect to the sql pod with the PostgreAdmin, but somehow i get this error , when i run the script:

> **Error**
>
> ```
> sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:~/NovaWebsocketServer$ ./start.sh
> got here
> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
> ```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the PostgreSQL username and password
PGUSER="admin"
PGPASSWORD="test123"

# Define the SQL script path
SQL_SCRIPT_PATH="/home/sanzor/NovaWebsocketServer/resources/tables.pgsql"

# Get the name of the PostgreSQL pod
POSTGRES_POD=$(kubectl get pods -l app=postgres -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
echo "got here"
# Use cat to insert the SQL script content into psql in the PostgreSQL pod
cat "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH" | sudo -S kubectl exec -it "$POSTGRES_POD" -- psql -U "$PGUSER" -d postgresdb

# Exit the script
exit
```

**Pod data**

```
sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:~/NovaWebsocketServer$ kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-7b9fb8d6c5-5s85s   1/1     Running   69         111d
```

**Pod description**

```
sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:~/NovaWebsocketServer$ kubectl describe pod postgres-7b9fb8d6c5-5s85s
Name:         postgres-7b9fb8d6c5-5s85s
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:   Sat, 15 Jul 2023 16:39:59 +0300
Labels:       app=postgres
              pod-template-hash=7b9fb8d6c5
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.2.108
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.2.108
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/postgres-7b9fb8d6c5
Containers:
  postgres:
    Container ID:   docker://661876a876e9e2e7be10c8c36f42804a9cb5de0a573d3352c7bd38b1b1043934
    Image:          postgres:10.1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://postgres@sha256:3f4441460029e12905a5d447a3549ae2ac13323d045391b0cb0cf8b48ea17463
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 04 Nov 2023 07:45:17 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 03 Nov 2023 15:38:42 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 04 Nov 2023 07:45:03 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  69
    Environment Variables from:
      postgres-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:       <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/postgresql/data from postgredb (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-wdg6m (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  postgredb:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  postgres-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-wdg6m:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From     Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----     -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  49m   kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Pulled          49m   kubelet  Container image "postgres:10.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created         49m   kubelet  Created container postgres
  Normal  Started         49m   kubelet  Started container postgres
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to run `kubectl`.  I might avoid `kubectl exec`; could you `kubectl port-forward` a port to the database container (again, without `sudo`) and then use `psql` locally?

Answer (score 1):

The `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` seems to be related to `kubectl` trying to read in the contents of `cat "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH"` -- the `tables.pgsql` is getting passed to `kubectl` and ends there, and doesn't make it all the way to `psql`.  I believe if you call `kubectl cluster-info` you should get something like:

```
root@sqa03:~# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
```

So when you `cat "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH" | sudo -S kubectl exec -it ...`, it's `kubectl` erroring out because it doesn't know what to do with the contents of `tables.pgsql`

Rather than `cat` the file into `sudo kubectl ...` I would recommend copying the file into the pod with `kubectl cp $SQL_SCRIPT_PATH <namespace>/<pod>:/path/to/tables.pgsql, then tell the pod to call` psql -f /path/to/tables.pgsql -U "$PGUSER" -d postgresdb`.

Comment: Running `kubectl cluster-info` renders this result:

`sanzor@DESKTOP-GOMS8S8:~/NovaWebsocketServer$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy`

Answer (score 1):

If you run `sudo kubectl config get-contexts` and see no cluster is listed, you need to copy the current user's ~/.kube/config to the root user's home directory first.

Comment: When i run this command there is indeed no cluster listed , however running `kubectl cluster-info` i get one.
Could you provide more info on how to do what you said ?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [doc](https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/the-connection-to-the-server-localhost8080-was-refused/) by Nijo Luca

Usually, The error occurs  when Kubernetes is unable to reach your cluster because it lacks the necessary permissions.

To resolve the issue, move the config file inside the kube folder.

**Try below troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue**

> If you're a regular user, use the following commands to set the
> correct ownership and move the configuration file into the kube
> folder.
>
> ```
> mkdir -p $HOME/.kube sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
> ```
>
> If you are a root user, export the KUBECONFIG environment variable
>
> ```
> export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
> ```
>
> Note: In most of the cases the configuration file is typically called
> admin.conf. If its name is different, modify the command according to
> that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was twofold.

1. As @gohm'c pointed out ,even though i was running with the default k8s context (docker-desktop) , running `kubectl config get-contexts` rendered no context

So what i did was

```
cd ~
ls -a .kube
sudo cp -R ~/.kube /root
```

2. Then my commands even though were running in a integrated terminal from visual studio code in the working directory , when running the script (located in the exact same folder) it appeared it was not running from that directory.

My updated script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the PostgreSQL username and password
PGUSER="admin"
PGPASSWORD="test123"

# Define the SQL script path
SQL_SCRIPT_PATH="/home/sanzor/NovaWebsocketServer/resources/tables.pgsql"

# Define the Kubernetes context you want to use
KUBE_CONTEXT="docker-desktop"

# Change the working directory to the location of the SQL script
cd "$(dirname "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH")"

# Get the name of the PostgreSQL pod
POSTGRES_POD=$(kubectl get pods -l app=postgres -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' --context="$KUBE_CONTEXT")

# Use kubectl cp to copy the SQL script to the PostgreSQL pod
kubectl cp "$(basename "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH")" "$POSTGRES_POD:$(basename "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH")" --context="$KUBE_CONTEXT"

# Change back to the original working directory
cd -

# Connect to the PostgreSQL pod and run the SQL script using sudo -S to provide the password
echo "$PGPASSWORD" | sudo -S kubectl exec -i "$POSTGRES_POD" -- psql -U "$PGUSER" -d postgresdb -f "$(basename "$SQL_SCRIPT_PATH")"

# Exit the script
exit
```